# Interruption of signal handler with other signal?

Tags: linux, unix, signals

Can a signal handler be interrupted by another signal (except of SIGKILL, SIGSTOP)?

Therefore, do I need to check for `EINTR` in my signal handler when calling interruptable syscalls?

(Linux and other Unixes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the execution of a signal handler may itself be interrupted by the delivery of another signal.

There are a few nuances, however.

By default, user-defined signal handlers temporarily block the very signal which invoked them.  This is the default behavior of [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) unless the SA_NODEFER flag is set.  (This is also the behavior of the older, discouraged [`signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) function, at least on most implementations.)

Additionally, `sigaction` can explicitly block signals during the handler's execution by setting the `sa_mask` member of the `const struct sigaction`.  Most code you see will explicitly empty this member during struct initialization, though it is often more robust to [`sigfillset`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigfillset.html) this member and not worry about interruptions.

So, again, yes.  Handle EINTR, `errno`, &c. as appropriate, or, better yet, design the handler to do no more than set a `sig_atomic_t` flag and avoid many worries.